# Sencha Jog with Friends example not working

Tags: extjs

I am attempting to get Sencha's Jog with Friend's example working. I have followed the set-up instructions precisely- setting up my MOngo DB, Facbeook app id and secret key, and starting the heroku app. When I build using their build.sh script, everything seems to work fine except I get the following error message: "create is not a command."

I know I have sencha CMD tools properly installed because I have used them to generate the starting example app, so I am not sure what else I need to do to use the "create" command?

Thanks!

Eric